# snakemake parameter function lambda

Tags: snakemake

I want to use a function on params.

```
Snakemake:
def mitico(x):
 res =int(x)+1
 return res
```

I I have a wildcard {sample} that are integer. And I want to use {sample}+1
How can do this inside the snakemake params?

In the  function:

```
rule create_pt:
    input:
        read="CALL2/{sample}.vcf",
    output:
        out="OUT/{sample}.txt
    conda:
         "envs/mb.yml"
    params:
         db_ens = "/mnt/mpwor2k/",
         fst = "/Homo_sapiens.GRCh37.75.dna.primary_assembly.fa",
         tumor_id="{sample}",
         normal_id=lambda wildcards: mitico('{sample}')



    shell:
```

I have this error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{sample}'
Wildcards:
sample=432
```

Answer (score 3):

`{sample}` in your lambda function is just a string and not wildcard. This is how to use wildcard in lambda

```
lambda wildcards: mitico(wildcards.sample)
```